# React Chakra ui Select is not updating selected option label on screen when selecting the options but is updating the state variable

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

React Chakra ui Select is not updating selected option label on screen when selecting the options but is updating the state variable.

```
class TaxClass{
  
    constructor () {
        this.taxes = [
            {
                lable:"18% GST",
                value:{value:18, valueType:"PERCENT",formLable:"18 %", taxType:"GST"},
   
            },
            {
                lable:"No TAX",
                value:{value:0, valueType:"ABSOLUTE",formLable:"0.0", taxType:"SIMPLE"},

            }

        ] 
        
      }

}

const [taxSelect, settaxSelect] = useState({
        lable:"No TAX",
        value:{value:0, valueType:"ABSOLUTE",formLable:"0.0", taxType:"SIMPLE"},

    });

const handleTaxSelect = (e) => {
        const localInvoice = cloneDeep(invoiceObject);

        if (e.target.options && e.target.selectedIndex) {
            
            const taxObj = new TaxClass();
            const selectedTaxconfig = taxObj.taxes[ e.target.selectedIndex - 1]['value'];
  
            localInvoice.selectedTaxProfile = selectedTaxconfig;
            localInvoice.recalculateAllInvoiceValues();
            settaxSelect(selectedTaxconfig);
            setInvoiceObject(localInvoice);
        }

    }

<Select name="taxselect" value={taxSelect} onChange={(e) => handleTaxSelect(e)} placeholder='Select option'>
                                    {taxes.taxes.map((ele) => <option key={ele.lable} value={ele.value}> {ele.lable} </option>)}
                                </Select>
```

tried to get the selected index from the Select on change event and set that index value from the option list the value in the state is changing but the onscreen option is not changing.